# What affects your credit score in Endless Sky?

Tags: endless-sky

Endless Sky improves upon the Escape Velocity series it was inspired by and modeled after by adding a banking/financial system, complete with loans/mortgages, interest rates, a credit score mechanic, and even death benefits (you pay relatives of the deceased when a crew member dies).

I understand the basics of how these work, including the credit score: a higher credit score means you can apply for larger loans with better interest rates, just like in the real world.

## My question:

**What factors determine your credit score, and how important is each relative to the others?**

Factors that seem relevant:

- Recent income (loans are higher when I have been making more money)
- Net worth
- Amount of debt (loans, bereavement, etc.)
- Capacity for repayment (combat rating? cargo capacity?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit score in endless sky is determined by when you make payments on loans it goes up 1 point each time you make a payment on time, and -5 when you miss one. The game tracks your net-worth over last 100 in game days in order to estimate your daily income which is what decides on how big of a loan you can get. The source being here in the game mechanics tab under loans and credit score. http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=545464233